# Unable to parse parameter: azuredeploy.parameters.json in Azure

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

Hi When I try to deploy storage Account after creating azuredeploy.json and azuredeploy.parameter.json using VS code I am getting the below error message

> "cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: Unable to parse parameter:
> azuredeploy.parameters.json az_command_data_logger: Unable to parse
> parameter: azuredeploy.parameters.json"

I used
`az  deployment group create --resource-group az204-arm-rg --template-file D:\Azure\azuredeploy.json --parameters azuredeploy.parameter` command in the terminal.

azuredeploy.json file has

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {"storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Storage Account Name",
            "minLength": 3,
            "maxLength": 24
        },

    }},
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "storageaccount1"
        },
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Premium_LRS",
            "tier": "Premium"
        }
    }],
    "outputs":{}

}
```

azuredeploy.parameters.json has

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "value": "az204storageacctarm" // TODO: Fill in parameter value
        }
    }
```

}

Error :-

[image]

Comment: Hello @sundar rajan, If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I used az deployment group create --resource-group az204-arm-rg
> --template-file D:\Azure\azuredeploy.json --parameters azuredeploy.parameter command in the terminal

It seems you have already filled all required parameters in your `azuredeploy.parameter.json` file .

The command you are trying to use by without providing parameter file path , try to use the below suggested command to deploy with parameter file by giving the ***path of parameter file***.

***e.g:-***

```
az deployment group create -n TestDeployment -g resourcegroup --template-file "C:\Users\source\repos\yourtemplatearm.json" --parameters "C:\users\source\repos\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
```

***NOTE:-*** Before deploy template make sure that you have logged in using `az login`

***Below are steps:-***

Default template that we tried to use and deploy .

`storagetest.json`-

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"location": {
"type": "string"
},
"storageAccountName": {
"type": "string"
},
"accountType": {
"type": "string"
},
"kind": {
"type": "string"
},
"accessTier": {
"type": "string"
},
"minimumTlsVersion": {
"type": "string"
},
"supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": {
"type": "bool"
},
"publicNetworkAccess": {
"type": "string"
},
"allowBlobPublicAccess": {
"type": "bool"
},
"allowSharedKeyAccess": {
"type": "bool"
},
"allowCrossTenantReplication": {
"type": "bool"
},
"defaultOAuth": {
"type": "bool"
},
"networkAclsBypass": {
"type": "string"
},
"networkAclsDefaultAction": {
"type": "string"
},
"dnsEndpointType": {
"type": "string"
},
"keySource": {
"type": "string"
},
"encryptionEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"keyTypeForTableAndQueueEncryption": {
"type": "string"
},
"infrastructureEncryptionEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"isContainerRestoreEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"isBlobSoftDeleteEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"blobSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
"type": "int"
},
"isContainerSoftDeleteEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"containerSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
"type": "int"
},
"changeFeed": {
"type": "bool"
},
"isVersioningEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"isShareSoftDeleteEnabled": {
"type": "bool"
},
"shareSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
"type": "int"
}
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
{
"name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
"apiVersion": "2021-09-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"properties": {
"accessTier": "[parameters('accessTier')]",
"minimumTlsVersion": "[parameters('minimumTlsVersion')]",
"supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "[parameters('supportsHttpsTrafficOnly')]",
"publicNetworkAccess": "[parameters('publicNetworkAccess')]",
"allowBlobPublicAccess": "[parameters('allowBlobPublicAccess')]",
"allowSharedKeyAccess": "[parameters('allowSharedKeyAccess')]",
"allowCrossTenantReplication": "[parameters('allowCrossTenantReplication')]",
"defaultToOAuthAuthentication": "[parameters('defaultOAuth')]",
"networkAcls": {
"bypass": "[parameters('networkAclsBypass')]",
"defaultAction": "[parameters('networkAclsDefaultAction')]",
"ipRules": []
},
"dnsEndpointType": "[parameters('dnsEndpointType')]",
"encryption": {
"keySource": "[parameters('keySource')]",
"services": {
"blob": {
"enabled": "[parameters('encryptionEnabled')]"
},
"file": {
"enabled": "[parameters('encryptionEnabled')]"
},
"table": {
"enabled": "[parameters('encryptionEnabled')]"
},
"queue": {
"enabled": "[parameters('encryptionEnabled')]"
}
},
"requireInfrastructureEncryption": "[parameters('infrastructureEncryptionEnabled')]"
}
},
"dependsOn": [],
"sku": {
"name": "[parameters('accountType')]"
},
"kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
"tags": {}
},
{
"name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
"apiVersion": "2021-09-01",
"properties": {
"restorePolicy": {
"enabled": "[parameters('isContainerRestoreEnabled')]"
},
"deleteRetentionPolicy": {
"enabled": "[parameters('isBlobSoftDeleteEnabled')]",
"days": "[parameters('blobSoftDeleteRetentionDays')]"
},
"containerDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
"enabled": "[parameters('isContainerSoftDeleteEnabled')]",
"days": "[parameters('containerSoftDeleteRetentionDays')]"
},
"changeFeed": {
"enabled": "[parameters('changeFeed')]"
},
"isVersioningEnabled": "[parameters('isVersioningEnabled')]"
},
"dependsOn": [
"[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
]
},
{
"name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileservices",
"apiVersion": "2021-09-01",
"properties": {
"shareDeleteRetentionPolicy": {
"enabled": "[parameters('isShareSoftDeleteEnabled')]",
"days": "[parameters('shareSoftDeleteRetentionDays')]"
}
},
"dependsOn": [
"[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
"[concat(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName')), '/blobServices/default')]"
]
}
],
"outputs": {}
}
```

`azuredeploy.parameter.json` -

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
    "location": {
    "value": "eastus"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
    "value": "yourstorageaccountname"
    },
    "accountType": {
    "value": "Standard_RAGRS"
    },
    "kind": {
    "value": "StorageV2"
    },
    "accessTier": {
    "value": "Hot"
    },
    "minimumTlsVersion": {
    "value": "TLS1_2"
    },
    "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": {
    "value": true
    },
    "publicNetworkAccess": {
    "value": "Enabled"
    },
    "allowBlobPublicAccess": {
    "value": true
    },
    "allowSharedKeyAccess": {
    "value": true
    },
    "allowCrossTenantReplication": {
    "value": true
    },
    "defaultOAuth": {
    "value": false
    },
    "networkAclsBypass": {
    "value": "AzureServices"
    },
    "networkAclsDefaultAction": {
    "value": "Allow"
    },
    "dnsEndpointType": {
    "value": "Standard"
    },
    "keySource": {
    "value": "Microsoft.Storage"
    },
    "encryptionEnabled": {
    "value": true
    },
    "keyTypeForTableAndQueueEncryption": {
    "value": "Account"
    },
    "infrastructureEncryptionEnabled": {
    "value": false
    },
    "isContainerRestoreEnabled": {
    "value": false
    },
    "isBlobSoftDeleteEnabled": {
    "value": true
    },
    "blobSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
    "value": 7
    },
    "isContainerSoftDeleteEnabled": {
    "value": true
    },
    "containerSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
    "value": 7
    },
    "changeFeed": {
    "value": false
    },
    "isVersioningEnabled": {
    "value": false
    },
    "isShareSoftDeleteEnabled": {
    "value": true
    },
    "shareSoftDeleteRetentionDays": {
    "value": 7
    }
    }
    }
```

***SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli#deployment-scope).